# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: But I don't use any alias

Tags: mysql

here is my query and i got this

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'user_rights'
```

error. i dont event think i have any excess commas or anything. what is the real error? my table name is user_rights, and i have tried to changed it maybe because its a built in funtion but it have the same error. heres my query

```
SELECT
            tbl_users.ID_NUM,
            tbl_users.USERNAME,
            user_rights.RIGHTS
        FROM tbl_users
            INNER JOIN user_group
            ON tbl_users.GROUP_ID = user_group.GROUP_ID
            INNER JOIN user_rights
            ON user_group.GROUP_ID = user_rights.GROUP_ID
            INNER JOIN user_rights
            ON user_group.GROUP_ID = user_rights.GROUP_ID
            INNER JOIN usertypes
            ON user_rights.RIGHTS = usertypes.USERCODE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem.

```
INNER JOIN user_rights
ON user_group.GROUP_ID = user_rights.GROUP_ID
INNER JOIN user_rights
ON user_group.GROUP_ID = user_rights.GROUP_ID
```

If you want to join the same table twice you *have to* use a table alias, like so:

```
INNER JOIN user_rights ur1
ON user_group.GROUP_ID = ur1.GROUP_ID
INNER JOIN user_rights ur2
ON user_group.GROUP_ID = ur2.GROUP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `user_rights` table twice.  I don't think that is necessary.  Also, the last `JOIN` also seems unnecessary.  Table aliases help make the query easier to write and to read.  So, I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT u.ID_NUM, u.USERNAME, ur.RIGHTS
FROM tbl_users u INNER JOIN
     user_group ug
     ON u.GROUP_ID = ug.GROUP_ID INNER JOIN
     user_rights ur
     ON ug.GROUP_ID = ur.GROUP_ID ;
```